# In DART: How can I access the element 1 of the list of String that is the value of the key 'respostas' of the element 1 of the main list of Map?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, maps

```dart
void main() {

  final List<Map<String, Object>> perguntas = [
      { 
      'texto': 'Qual é a sua cor favorita?',
      'respostas': ['Preto', 'Vermelho', 'Verde','Branco'],
      },
       { 
      'texto': 'Qual é o seu animal favorito?',
      'respostas': ['Coelho', 'Cobra', 'Elefante','Leão'],
      }, { 
      'texto': 'Qual é o seu instrutor favorito?',
      'respostas': ['Jacob', 'Rodrigo', 'Daniel','Leo'],
      },
      ];
}
```

How can I access the element 1 of the list of String that is the value of the key  `respostas` of the element 1 of the main list of Map?

> [Coelho, Cobra, Elefante, Leão] ---> I want to access the element 1: 'Elefante'

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

On [dartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=eef18f25f6d9a489e70c5a8892fbfdce&null_safety=true) or [gist](https://gist.github.com/yeasin50/eef18f25f6d9a489e70c5a8892fbfdce)

`Main function`

```dart
void main() {
  final List<Map<String, Object>> perguntas = [
    {
      'texto': 'Qual é a sua cor favorita?',
      'respostas': ['Preto', 'Vermelho', 'Verde', 'Branco'],
    },
    {
      'texto': 'Qual é o seu animal favorito?',
      'respostas': ['Coelho', 'Cobra', 'Elefante', 'Leão'],
    },
    {
      'texto': 'Qual é o seu instrutor favorito?',
      'respostas': ['Jacob', 'Rodrigo', 'Daniel', 'Leo'],
    },
  ];

  int? foundValueAt;

  print(perguntas.length);

  for (int i = 0; i < perguntas.length; i++) {
    final items = perguntas[i]['respostas'] as List<String>;

    // finding where `Elefante` contains
    print(items.contains("Elefante") ? "YEs" : "NO");
    if (foundValueAt == null && items.contains("Elefante")) {
      foundValueAt = i;

      ///finding index of `Elefante` inside of list<String>
      final index = items.indexWhere((element) => element == 'Elefante');
      print("index of Elefante => $index");

      ///let's change the value
      perguntas[i]['respostas'] = items
        ..removeAt(index)
        ..add("newValue");
    }
  }

  print('Elefante found onMainList:  index $foundValueAt');
  print("new Value>> ");
  perguntas.forEach((e) {
    print(e.toString());
  });
}
```

**Result**

```
3
NO
YEs
index of Elefante => 2
NO
Elefante found onMainList:  index 1
new Value>> 
{texto: Qual é a sua cor favorita?, respostas: [Preto, Vermelho, Verde, Branco]}
{texto: Qual é o seu animal favorito?, respostas: [Coelho, Cobra, Leão, newValue]}
{texto: Qual é o seu instrutor favorito?, respostas: [Jacob, Rodrigo, Daniel, Leo]}
```